# Windows -> samba - slow write speed

Tags: linux, networking, debian, samba

I have a Debian linux machine with samba Version 4.13.13-Debian on a peer-to-peer network. I've just run a LAN speed test, and it gives a considerably slower write speed from Windows -> Debian, than Windows -> Windows.  Here are the stats:

```
Win -> Samba: Write 439.0 Mbps, Read 684.0 Mbps
Win -> Win:   Write 758.5 Mbps, Read 655.9 Mbps
```

Here is the [globals] section of smb.conf

```
[global]
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba %v)
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n .
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
socket options = TCP_NODELAY
dns proxy = No
invalid users = root
printing = cups
printcap name = cups
time server = yes
dos filetimes = yes
fake directory create times = yes
dos filetime resolution = yes
delete readonly = yes
log level = 1
read raw = yes
write raw = yes
```

I'd welcome any suggestions

Comment: CLEARLY not an answer but I too was presented with this same dilemma.  Not only did the performance suck (for me), managing the smb,.conf to get what I actually wanted was dizzying (perhaps I am not smart enough).  Now, I keep the share on the windows side and mount that share from the Linux side.  My linux boxes only need smbclient, the performance is good enough, and everyone is happy.  I hope someone can answer your question.

Comment: Which SMB version are you using for both connections, and is encryption in use, according to `get-smbconnection | ft ServerName,ShareName,Dialect,Encrypted` from the Windows client side? Have you measured the regular TCP throughput using `iperf3` between the hosts (i.e. not involving their storage)?

Comment: I'll need to nut out iperf3. Here's the output:PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-smbconnection | ft ServerName,ShareName,Dialect,Encrypted: 
Dialect: 3.1.1, Encrypted: false

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom with my samba file server. Problem seems to be the SMB3 protocol.
As a workaround, add the following line to the `[global]` section:

```
server max protocol = SMB2_10
```